# How to write a recursive function with initial condition in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, definition

In F# I can define like this:

```
let rec sum = function
| [] -> 0
| x::xs -> x + sum xs
```

Looks quite convenient. Is there its correspondence in Haskell?

Comment: `let sum [] = 0 ; sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs` (GHCi definition dialect).

Comment: For this kind of issues, I recommend [Haskell for OCaml programmers](http://science.raphael.poss.name/haskell-for-ocaml-programmers.html#straightforward-equivalences) (even if I don't completely agree on all its suggestions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int

sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

Another way

```
 Prelude>:{
 Prelude|let sumE  xs' = case xs' of
 Prelude|                     [] -> 0
 Prelude|                     x:xs' -> x + sumE xs'
 Prelude| 
 Prelude|:}
 Prelude> sumE [1,2,3]
 6
 Prelude> sumE []
 0
```

Comment: Prelude seems to forbid having multiple lines of code. Each time I type "enter", the expression is evaluated. How did your example work? Thanks.

Comment: :set +m for multiline mode

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the feature you like is "I don't have to repeat the name `sum`", the `LambdaCase` extension enables this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

module CaseExample where
import Prelude hiding (sum)

sum = \case
    [] -> 0
    x:xs -> x + sum xs
```

Otherwise, the syntax that works without extensions is

```
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

Comment: I tried first one on ghc, got syntax error:let sum = \case
 []->0
 x:xs->x+sum xs

sum [1..10]. It says parse error on input `case'

Comment: @vik: You need to allow for the extension `LambdaCase` in ghci. Before typing `let sum  = ...`, you should type in ghci `:set -XLambdaCase`. See  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584884/how-do-i-enable-language-extensions-from-within-ghci).

Comment: Thanks, it works in ghci. But if I wish to use GHC to compile my code, how do I import? I tried "import LambdaCase", still says "parse error on input `case'. Am I using wrong import?

Comment: @viksantata The first code block in my answer is a complete file you can compile.

Answer (score 1):

This will alow you to write multiple lines of code:

```
  Prelude> :set +m
```

Then try this code. The prompt changes from prelude> to prelude|  :

```
Prelude> let sumE  xs' = case xs' of
Prelude|                     [] -> 0
Prelude|                     x:xs' -> x + sumE xs'
```